# Oracle Trigger for adding Old Val and New Val to audit table?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am wanting to created an Oracle Trigger that will execute on Update on the table "User"

**User**

- ID
- Department
- Privilege
- Hashkey

The Oracle trigger will then add rows to the following table "Audit"

**Audit**

- User ID
- Field Name
- Old_Val
- New_Val
- Date

Where it will record the changes of a specific field's Old value and New value and when it was changed.

My questions are:

- How does it know which Field is being updated to then create a row in the Audit table to record the Old and New value of that changed field
- How can I get my trigger to work when more than one field is being updated in the Update Transaction?

Is an Oracle trigger going to work for this?

Here is my code so far (it is not functional as I do not know what to put as the argument for field)

Code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER_UPDATE_TRG
BEFORE UPDATE OF USER_ID,Department, Privilege, Hashkey 
ON USER
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO AUDIT
  (
  USER_ID,
  FIELD_NAME,
  OLD_VAL,
  NEW_VAL,
  CHANGED_DATE
  )
  VALUES
  (
  USER_ID,
  <what do I put here for Field Name?,
  :old.Field,
  :new.Field,
  sysdate  
  )
END;
```

Comment: Another approach for data auditing or for recording olddata is explained here http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/complete-data-audit.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UPDATING` conditional predicate to identify the fieldname.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER_UPDATE_TRG
BEFORE UPDATE OF USER_ID,Department, Privilege, Hashkey 
ON USER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF UPDATING ('USER_ID') THEN 
          INSERT INTO AUDIT
          (
          USER_ID,
          FIELD_NAME,
          OLD_VAL,
          NEW_VAL,
          CHANGED_DATE
          )
          VALUES
          (
          :new.USER_ID,
          'USER_ID',
          :old.USER_ID,
          :new.USER_ID,
          SYSDATE  
          );
     END IF;

     IF UPDATING ('DEPARTMENT') THEN
          .....
     END IF;

     IF UPDATING ('PRIVILEGE') THEN
          .....
     END IF;

     IF UPDATING ('HASHKEY') THEN
          .....
     END IF;
END;
```

In this case if multiple columns are updated, the trigger will insert multiple records in table audit.

Edited:

the trigger you have written is statement level trigger.
the `:NEW` AND `:OLD` qualifiers will work in row level trigger for that you have to mention `FOR EACH ROW`.

I have added that in my code.

Comment: It looks like your solution will only create 1 record in the audit table. If user_id is being updated it will skip the rest of the elsif's wouldn't it?

Comment: @Rene , yea I think you are right, the Trigger will need to understand if its a multiple field update or a single field transaction

Comment: Getting a Error: ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
Something about I need to use "AS" or "DECLARE"

Comment: @serupticious, i don't think you need to use `DECLARE` for this requirement. You might have use some invalid statements in your code. Can you please share your modified trigger code.

Comment: The issue might be with `USER_ID` in your insert query. Try to remove it with `:new.user_id`.